# C++ 4.8 Runtime Heap corruption

Tags: c++, qt, heap-memory, heap-corruption

We are working with Qt 4.8, but I honestly believe this has nothing to do with it (but I point it out just in case)

We created this class that compiles just fine but crashes on runtime with the following error:

***ERROR:
53:01
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in C_plus_plus_QT_project.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in C_plus_plus_QT_project.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while C_plus_plus_QT_project.exe has focus.
The output window may have more diagnostic information.***

The problem is that QFrame m_FrameHeader; is declared on the .h file and the on the class constructor we go and do:

```
QFrame m_FrameHeader(this);
```

I am honestly surprised this compiles. If this would've been a test and anyone would have asked me what the result would be, I'd have said this would not compile because of a variable redefinition, ambiguity or something along those lines. But this totally does compile and crashes on runtime with the previously mentioned Heap Corruption error.

Can anyone explain why does it compile and, when it crashes, it crashes as a heap corruption error instead of a stack [whatever] error? Why the heap and not the stack? I already solved the issue (it builds ok, and runs ok) but I couldn't explain why it behaves like this instead of what I would've expected (compilation error and, if that's wrong, I would have expected it to be a stack error, not Heap)

We expect code to be bad, because we are playing around with Qt right now, so we are not paying any attention to its quality. Please disregard it (unless you believe it's part of the issue at hand, in that case please do point it out as much as you need, haha).

Our environment: Qt 4.8.2, VS2010, Windows 7 x64.

this is the .h

```
#include <QtGui\QWidget>
#include <QtGui\QLabel>
#include <QtGui\QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui\QVBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui\QGridLayout>
#include <QtGui\QFrame>

class Quiniela : public QWidget
{
private:
    QLabel m_Fecha;
    QLabel m_Titulo;
    QLabel m_Hora;
    QHBoxLayout m_HeaderLayout;
    QFrame m_FrameHeader;
    QHBoxLayout m_SorteosLayout;
    QHBoxLayout m_EntesLayout;
    QGridLayout m_MainLayout;
public:
    Quiniela(int w = 800, int h = 600,QWidget* parent = 0);
    ~Quiniela();
};
```

and this is the .cpp

```
#include "Quiniela.h"
#include "FramePrincipal.h"
#include "Utils.h"

Quiniela::Quiniela(int w, int h, QWidget * parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    Utils objUtil;
    QFont fontHead("Arial", 24, QFont::Black);
    QFont fontSorteos("Arial", 20, QFont::Normal);
    resize(w,h);
    setWindowTitle("QUINIELA");
    QFrame m_FrameHeader(this);
    m_FrameHeader.setGeometry(0,0,800,50);
    m_Fecha.setText(objUtil.getDate());
    m_Fecha.setFont(fontHead);
    m_Titulo.setText("*** QUINIELA ***");
    m_Titulo.setFont(fontHead);
    m_Hora.setText(objUtil.getTime());
    m_Hora.setFont(fontHead);
    m_HeaderLayout.addWidget(&m_Fecha,0,Qt::AlignLeft);
    m_HeaderLayout.addWidget(&m_Titulo,0,Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_HeaderLayout.addWidget(&m_Hora,0,Qt::AlignRight);
    m_HeaderLayout.setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);
    m_FrameHeader.setLayout(&m_HeaderLayout);
}

Quiniela::~Quiniela()
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use pointers for Qt objects (Qt maintains parent-child link for its objects via pointers, and destroys children on parent delete). In your example m_FrameHeader is destroyed as constructor returns, since it's declared as a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

There's no compiler error because `QFrame m_FrameHeader(this)` declares a new (local) variable called m_FrameHeader. This *should* generate a warning from the compiler that you're hiding the class variable of the same name. Are you sure it didn't? Anyway, the crash happens because m_FrameHeader is destroyed once the constructor returns, yet it is still referenced by things that aren't destroyed. Such as m_HeaderLayout.

Comment: Thank you, this was a very simple and clear explanation. I would upvote it but I do not have the reputation.

Comment: It's a misleading explanation. The crash happens not because `m_FrameHeader` is referenced by anything. It happens because `m_FrameHeader` has children, and `delete`s the children, and they were not individually allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is deletion of objects that are not directly allocated on the heap.

Initially, the widgets you put within `Quiniela` class are parentless.

Eventually you install them in the `m_headerLayout` layout, and they will be reparented to the widget that you set the layout on.

The line `m_FrameHeader.setLayout(&m_HeaderLayout)` sets the parent of `m_Fecha`, `m_Titulo` and `m_Hora` to `m_FrameHeader`.

Now notice that `m_FrameHeader` is a local, stack-allocated variable that you defined in the line `QFrame m_FrameHeader(this)`. It goes out of scope at the end of `Quiniela` constructor. When a QObject with children is destroyed, it will invoke `delete` on all of the children. Yet those children, specifically `m_Fecha`, `m_Titulo` and `m_Hora` have not been allocated on the heap using `new`.

Even if you fix the mistake of hiding the class member `m_FrameHeader`, you still won't fix the crash. It will be merely delayed until the destruction of the instance of `Quiniela`.

The only way to fix it is to allocate all the widgets on the heap. Your widget should look like this:

```
class Quiniela : public QWidget
{
private:

    QLabel * m_Fecha;
    QLabel * m_Titulo;
    QLabel * m_Hora;
    QHBoxLayout * m_HeaderLayout;
    QFrame * m_FrameHeader;
    QHBoxLayout * m_SorteosLayout;
    QHBoxLayout * m_EntesLayout;
    QGridLayout * m_MainLayout;
    ...

};
```

You do not need to delete any of those objects explicitly. Qt will do it for you, since they will end up being reparented to the Quiniela widget instance.

Comment: I know this post is so old it should have a cane, but as I am sure you already know, when you say *the only way to fix it is to allocate all the widgets on the heap*, it is not exactly true. You can also fix it by changing the declaration order of the class members. Destroy the children before the parent and it will work fine.